# Как сделать связи @OneToOne и @ManyToOne в Spring-проекте и таблицах БД?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Spring изучаю совсем недавно, поэтому заранее извиняйте. Пишу проект, где имеется три сущности - это `Админ, Повар и Пользователь`. Насколько я понял, лучше в БД не создавать для каждого класса отдельную таблицу, а сделать одну таблицу User со всеми основными полями, а уже потом к ней через связи соединять остальные(я не знаю как это правильно называется). Вопрос следующий: как реализовать все это в java-коде и как это сделать в таблицах БД. Правильно ли я понимаю, что нам необходима связь `@OneToOne`.

User:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity // позволяет включать класс и его jpa аннотации в производный класс,
                    // не делая базовый класс сущностью.
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User {

    public User(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public User(String name, String lastName, String role,
                String login, String password){ // Базовый конструктор для дочерних классов

        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Admin:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class Admin extends User {

    public Admin(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Admin(String name, String lastName, String role, String login, String password) { // Вызываем родительский конструктор
        super(name, lastName, role, login, password);
    }

    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

//    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "pg_user")
//    private User user;

    // Поля name, lastName, role, login, password наследуются от класса User;
}
```

Cook:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonBackReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.CookService;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.CookType;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "cook", schema = "public")
public class Cook extends User {

    public Cook(){ // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }

    public Cook(String name, String lastName, String role, String login, String password,
                CookType cookType, float rating, boolean cookStatus,
                List<Review> reviewList, String aboutCook){ // Вызываем родительский конструктор вместе со своими полями

        super(name, lastName, role, login, password);
        this.cookType = cookType;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.cookStatus = cookStatus;
        this.reviewList = reviewList;
        this.aboutCook = aboutCook;
    }

    // Поля
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;

    private CookType cookType;

    private float rating;

    private boolean cookStatus;


    // Поля name, lastName, login, password наследуются от класса User;
}
```

Comment: а кто к кому должен OneToOne ссылаться?

Comment: Админ, Повар и Заказчик к User

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы таблица повара в бд не содержала Имя, Фамилия и возраст например, а каким-то образом забирала из таблицы User

Comment: @ArturVartanyan скорее всего тут не нужна связь один-к-одному, почитайте про [наследование в hibernate](https://easyjava.ru/data/jpa/nasledovanie-v-jpa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы обеспечить связь *@OneToOne* мы в классе `Cook`:

```java
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") // Join without Cook in User class
    private User user;
```

При этом в таблице `Cook` создаем ключ со ссылкой на `id` таблицы `User`.

```sql
user_id int references user(id) on update cascade on delete cascade;
```

Чтобы обеспечить связь *@OneToMany* мы в классе `Cook`:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cook", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private List<Review> reviewList;
```

А в классе `Review` пишем:

```java
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference// Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
    private Cook cook;
```

В таблице `review` создаем ключ с привязкой к `id` `cook`:

```sql
cook_id int references cook(id) on update cascade on delete cascade;
```